# How to identify the emacs keybinding for something in the GUI?

Tags: email, emacs

I started using mu4e for email in emacs recently, and while I was successfully able to configure my email and get comfortable with the general navigations for keys, I can't seem to find the good old fashioned "send-message" keybinding that's C-ENTER for a lot of email clients.

I've looked through [this excellent list](http://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Keybindings.html#Keybindings), but wasn't there.

I know my configuration works because when I click that button the GUI here, where the cursor is, it sends:

[image]

So, I'm wondering two things:

1. Minor question: what is the function that is sending email?  I'm using smtpmail, I think, for my actual send, if that changes anything.
2. Major question: What's the best way to identify the keystrokes that control the functions in the GUI?  (I'm using emacs so I don't have to click buttons!)

Comment: my attempt: I think C-c C-c will send the mail.

Comment: The function should be something like `message-send-and-exit`.

Answer (score 11):

The answer to the major question:

- Type `C-h k` and then click the toolbar button.  It won't actually perform the action, but pop up a help buffer that tells you the name of the function.
- Then type `C-h w` (for "where is") and type the name of that function.  That will tell you what keys, if any, are bound to that function.

Answer (score 2):

Also try <kbd>C-h m</kbd>. This shows you the current modes (including the major mode) *and its keymaps*. The keymap for the major mode is the most important thing. There you see which function is bound to which key.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the minor question: `C-c C-c` will send the mail: http://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Useful-keybindings.html#Useful-keybindings so see the function with `C-h k RET C-c-c`. It may be that one: http://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Sending-mail.html#Sending-mail

C-c-c is the usual keybinding to hem… «validate buffers» (like in commit mode with magit and I forgot other examples). `C-c C-k` would cancel.

Answer (score 1):

`C-h m`, `C-h k`, `C-h b`, and `C-h w` are helpful, but they only get you so far.

[***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles) [key completion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Key_Completion) lets you know, in any given context, just (a) [what inputs are possible](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsNewbieWithIcicles#PossibleInputs); (b) [which keys are available](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsNewbieWithIcicles#PossibleKeyBindings); and (c) [what they do](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsNewbieWithIcicles#KeyHelpAndCompletion).

For example, `S-TAB M-q` does both what `C-h w` (`where-is`) does and what `C-h c` (`describe-key-briefly`) does.  It also does what `C-h b` (`describe-bindings`) does.

Key completion can be handy in several ways, and it can teach you various things about keys and commands as you use it