# how to find out what command correspond to each menu item in emacs?

Tags: emacs

For example, in this screenshot,

[image]

I would like to find out what command is called by
clicking on Python->Execute statement.

Comment: `C-h k` and then click on the menu item.

Comment: @lawlist: Please post your comment as an answer (it is the answer).

Comment: See also [this question](http://superuser.com/q/699388/4542).

Answer (score 5):

The keyboard combination `C-h k` can be used to obtain information about functions linked to certain menu items or other keys.  In the context of this question, entering `C-h k` and then clicking on the menu item will display the name of the function and additional helpful information (e.g., the doc string sometimes can be very useful).